# Postgresql coalesce analog for query union

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, coalesce

I have a query like this

```
select house, street, town, 10 as weight 
from addresses
where 
    house match query,
    street match query,
    city match query
union all 
select house, street, town, 5
    from addresses
where 
    street match query,
    city match query
```

And I want the second one query been executed **only if** the first one is empty. I know that I can add where clause and check for the results of previous query, but If I add 3 or 4 optional sub queriesthat becomes too bulky.

I know that it's doable with plpgsql, but maybe there is already tested standard function or syntax for that?

Answer (score 1):

One deliberate feature of queries unioned together is that they can't refer to each other.  The best bet you have is to wrap more sql around what you have.

One option could be to add another column *(maybe called `source_id`)*, then use windowed functions to find the lowest `source_id`, then filter using that.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c1004/1

```
WITH
  source_data AS
(
  SELECT 1 as source_id, * FROM test WHERE x > 10
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as source_id, * FROM test WHERE x < 10
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as source_id, * FROM test WHERE x = 10
),
  source_scanned AS
(
  SELECT
    MIN(source_id) OVER () AS min_source_id,
    *
  FROM
    source_data
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  source_scanned
WHERE
  source_id = min_source_id
```

That, however, means executing all the queries and running some processing over the top of all of the results.  Personally, I'd use `plpgsql` *(insert results in to a temp table, iterate over your queries until any rows are actually inserted)*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional union:

```
with main as (
  select house, street, town, 10 as weight 
  from addresses
  where ...
)
select *
from main
union all 
select *
from addresses
where ...
 and not exists (select *
                 from main
                 limit 1);
```

The `LIMIT 1` in the sub-select is probably not necessary, because the Postgres query planer is smart enough, but it won't hurt either.

Comment: That works ok for two queries, but what if I want to add more?